# Can I create an AnyLogic supply chain model to have retailers create orders referencing a database table using a cyclic event?

Tags: anylogic

We currently have a supply chain model that generates orders from a statechart in the retailer agent based on a weekly order rate pulled from a database table. We would like to modify this model to generate single orders (instead of weekly orders) based on a date time specified in the database table.

We were instructed to create a cyclic event (occurs every second) that compares the running model time to the time stored in the database. We created the event but are unsure what logic/code we need to add to the event and/or elsewhere in order for it to compare the running model time to the date time stored in the database so it can generate the order.

We believe we need to change our statechart to generate orders based on a condition or message and are unsure how to incorporate this feature as well. In the provided image the selected transition is where we believe where a message or condition should be checked/sent to work with the event (this is the transition that previously contained the weekly order rate).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MUAu.png)

Answer (score 0):

i would do it differently:

1. on the beginning of the simulation, read the database and calculate the difference between the current datetime and the order datetime for each order... let's call this time difftime (in seconds)
2. for each order, create a dynamic event that will start after difftime seconds that takes as arguments all the characteristics of the order

In other words, you don't need a statechart